# Can someone verify that I'm interpreting this sql statement properly?

Tags: sql

I'm using rails and a plugin to manage tags - The query I'm using involves
- a tasks table (many to many relationship with users)
- a tags table ( stores reference to a tag - id (int), name (string) )
- a taggable table (polymorphic table that references a tag, the taggable item, and the tagger of that item, in my case, tasks)

Here is the sql:

ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.1ms)

```
SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE (lower(name) = '#sharedtag')
```

Task Load (0.4ms)

```
SELECT "tasks".* 
FROM "tasks" INNER JOIN "task_relationships" 
ON "tasks"."id" = "task_relationships"."task_id" 
JOIN taggings tasks_taggings_f7b47be 
ON tasks_taggings_f7b47be.taggable_id = tasks.id 
AND tasks_taggings_f7b47be.taggable_type = 'Task' 
AND tasks_taggings_f7b47be.tag_id = 23 
WHERE "task_relationships"."user_id" = 1 
ORDER BY tasks.created_at DESC
```

What I'm confused about is line 3 of the task load, where `tasks_taggings_f7b47be.tag_id` shows up out of nowhere. I assume it's some sort of temporary table or reference to a created join table, but have only recently started exploring sql.

Any explanation, links, or general knowledge would be appreciated.

Comment: SQL-based relational databases require an intermediary table to describe a many-to-many relationship, rather than the usual one-to-many. Since most languages/object models can natively accommodate a many-to-many relationship without an intermediary entity, an auto-generated table is created in the database to fill in this gap in the relational model. The hexadecimal number at the end is usually there to ensure the table name is unique, and its ugliness is excused because it should never be visible to the developer from within the language/framework/ORM.

Comment: THank you for your answer. The first line in your answer states that 'SQL-based relational db's require...'; does that mean that were I to attempt this same query by hand writing my SQL, that I would have to alias this table manually as seen in the query generated by rails and ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think tasks_taggings_f7b47be  is an alias to the taggings table => http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

It is permissible to omit the AS keyword: 
"The general syntax of an alias is SELECT * FROM table_name [AS] alias_name. Note that the AS keyword is completely optional and is usually kept for readability purposes." [more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28SQL%29)

Comment: Thank you, that is what I initially thought. Can you expand on your answer a bit as to WHY the ORM needs to create that temporary table? I'm going to ask Allon Guralnek, who commented on my answer above the same thing to further my understanding of SQL.

Comment: @Squadrons: Sorry, I misread the SQL code. qbantek is correct, it is simply an alias, which means another name to refer to a table within a query. It doesn't create another table, merely gives it an additional name (usually shorter, for convenience, like in `select v.Id, v.Name from VeryLongTableName v`). ORMs use aliases for internal purposes. Readability of the SQL they generate is not their primary concern. Any time you see `tasks_taggings_f7b47be` it really means `taggings`.

Comment: Correct, not a temporary table: just a temporary name for the same table. You usually do this to increase readability and to refer to tables by a shorter and easier to type name. I am not sure what logic or objective is the ORM following here, like Allon says, is probably for internal usage.